# how to prevent mysql data file being copied out

Tags: mysql

Just wondering is there any ways to prevent mysql data files being copied by others.

I am a developer with mysql as database, i want to protect my tables so no one are possible to copy the table and used it with their own program, or simply to put i don't want other to see my table design.

As we are aware that mysql contains 3 files for each table in the mysql folder, so anyone can copy those files and put it into their own server.

Comment: The filesystem access is a system administration question and presumably irrelevant to mysql at all. What operating system do you use? BeOS? Plan9?

Comment: How can someone copy your data?

Comment: most of my customer have windows as their OS. When we installed the program to our customer, we will have to install mysql server as well, so the administrator is always has the ability to copy out the data files. I am looking for a way to prevent them to copy the datafiles or the datafiles unuseable if they are able to copy it. Something like access which we can password protected the mdb file.

Comment: @user3077209: if you have admin/root permissions on a machine - you can do whatever you want.

Comment: You **give** the user the data files, that they put on their machine, that they have to access the contents of, to run your application. Then ask how to stop them doing what they want with the data that you **gave** them complete access to? You sure you want to continue with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no MySQL specific way to achieve that.

If you mean something like file encryption, MYSQL doesn't support that natively.

Have a look at this 3rd party product:

http://www.vormetric.com/products/encryption/database-encryption

But as zerkms correctly commented:

> if you have admin/root permissions on a machine - you can do whatever
>   you want.

Comment: Maybe other ways or third party software can do that